# PHP MySQL INSERT stops working when adding a variable as a VALUE

Tags: php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $passport = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 20);

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","php","","A");

  $query = "INSERT INTO users (nickname, passport, mail, password, age, sex, is_registered)
            VALUES ('$_POST[nickname]', '$passport', '$_POST[mail]', md5('$_POST[password]'), '$_POST[age]', '$_POST[sex]', '1')";

  $result = $link->query($query);

}
?>
```

Removing `passport`, and `$passport` from the `$query` makes it work again?

A `echo "$passport";` also works. No errors reported.

Comment: 1. You are wide open to SQL injections 2. MD5 is no longer secure and should never be used for hashing passwords 3. You are missing quotes around your array keys for `$_POST`

Comment: And what is the result of `echo "$passport";`?

Comment: Injections.. injections everywhere

Comment: @PatrickQ Example is 9ELPVYMQAZ2H6J1X73KU.

Comment: @user2656114 And what about `echo $query;`? What's the datatype definition for the `passport` column in your db?

Comment: You should be checking for, and then displaying SQL errors.  `if($result === FALSE){ die($link->error); }`.  Also, as previously stated, this code is *very unsafe*.  You should be using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (and not using MD5 for passwords).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 md5($_POST['password'])
```

instead of

```
md5('$_POST[password]')
```

CODE:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (nickname, passport, mail, password, age, sex, is_registered)
    VALUES ('$_POST[nickname]', '$passport', '$_POST[mail]', '".md5($_POST['password'])."', '$_POST[age]', '$_POST[sex]', '1')";
```

Comment: MySQL has an [`MD5()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) function too.